# Obtener valor de variable indirectamente en Matlab

Tags: matlab

Tengo el nombre de n variables almacenadas en un struct "lista", y quisiera mostrar el valor de las variables mediante la posición del struct, es decir:

```
 var_1=3


 lista{1}='var_1'
```

de tal modo que al indicar `lista{1}` me imprima **`3`**, y no la cadena **`'var_1'`**.

Answer (score 0):

Podría funcionar si solo quitas las comillas simples, esto asignara el valor que tiene la variable y no un string.

```
var_1 = 3;
lista{1} = var_1
lista = 
     [3] . . .
      .
      .
      .
```

Comment: Sí asi funciona, pero las string no las almaceno manualmente, sino que se genera automaticamente a partir de las variables existentes, entonces no podría hacer la asignación que indicas.